# Javascript Swap Image on .this Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to perform a simple image swap when an image is clicked. I am looping through a database so I have a bunch of "thumbs up" images. when a user clicks on one of the images, I would like that particular image to turn green. the two image names are "thumbs_up.png" and "thumbs_up_green.png"

I can get the image to disappear using ".this" but cannot figure out how to make the image swap. Any help would be great! Thank you!

**Here is my script:**

```
<script>
    function thumbTip(element){
        var name = element.name;
        $(element).hide();
    }
</script>
```

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<table width='100%' class='test'>
    <tr>
        <td><span class='test'>$p[first_name]</span></td>
        <td align='center'><span class='test'>$p[date_time]</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='87%'><span class='test2'>$p[tip]</span></td>
        <td width='13%' align='center'>
            <span class='test3'>
                <a href='#' onClick='thumbTip(this)'>
                    <img src='../images/thumbs_up.png' width='25' scalefit='1' />
                </a>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You could store the src value for the second image as an attribute on the img tag. Then on click using jQuery you could just swap the two. Will try and find a nice example of what i mean. Also a nicer solution may be to add/remove a class from the image tag so that the image is in the css. That way jQuery's add/remove class methods could be used with hasClass() for a simple if check

Comment: thanks lewis! appreciate the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have tagged jQuery . Will give a jQuery solution..

```
$('.test3 a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $img = $(this).find('img');

    $img.attr('src', function(_,s) {
         return s.indexOf('thumbs_up_green') > -1 ? '../images/thumbs_up.png'
                                                  : '../images/thumbs_up_green.png'
    });
});
```

Just swapping out the src attribute of the image based in the condition.

Comment: And e.preventDefault() to not follow the link?

Comment: WOOOOHOOOOOO - This is EXACTLY what I was looking for, and it looks great. you rock!!

Comment: Glad to have been of help.. If you want vanilla javascript solution you can try this as well http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/NA6hj/

Answer (score 1):

In the below you would have two css classes with the images named thumbs-up and thumbs-up-green and each time you are just toggling which one is on the element.

```
function thumbTip(element){
    var el = $(element);

    el.toggleClass("thumbs-up");
    el.toggleClass("thumbs-up-green");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps toggleClass would save some lines? Also some explanation that you are manipulating CSS instead of swapping images would be in order

Comment: Can't believe I used the word toggle in the description yet completely forgot about toggleClass() itself. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Could you explain please?

Comment: Just have `el.toggleClass("thumbs-up-green");` If it was not set before it is after click and removed again on next click

Comment: That's a different way of doing it but I don't think it means I've used toggleClass() incorrectly. If you only toggle one class then you either have to default the img tag to have the "thumbs-up" class or give it a src. If you default it's class then - for example - to find/query all that have the "thumbs-up" class you would then have to exclude any that also had the "thumbs-up-green" class. If you go with defaulting the img tag's src attribute then you have to go down the !important route to make sure the CSS overrides the html. I think my way avoids both of these scenarios.

Comment: Yes, you DO have to default the class, and that is no different from the default src being thumbs-up. Oh well many ways to skin a cat

Answer (score 0):

**And here a solution in plain JS**

I would suggest to swap the thumbs-image in two steps:

1. Check which image is shown at the moment.
2. Then change the image an proceed further code.

For example:

```
<script>
    function thumbTip(element){
        if(element.src == '../images/thumbs_up.png'){
            element.src = '../images/thumbs_up_green.png';

            //Further Code: (when thumb gets green) 

        }else{
            element.src = '../images/thumbs_up.png';

            //Further Code: (when thumb gets normal again) 

        }
    }
```

Note: May a absolute path to the img would be better in this case.

Comment: He is passing (this) which is the link, to the image

Comment: Sorry, read it too fast. Based on my JS-plain-solution, the "onClick='thumbTip(this)'" attribute should be placed in the img tag!